# Visual Studio Code always on top

Tags: visual-studio-code

**How to set Visual Studio Code always on top?**

I want to set VS Code on Windows to be always on top of other windows.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is currently not possible. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15430) on GitHub.

As read from the issue

> This feature request will not be considered in the next 6-12 months roadmap and as such will be closed to keep the number of issues we have to maintain actionable. Thanks for understanding and happy coding!

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case? I mean. I'm trying to resolve an issue of my vs code window being always ontop. I'm unsure if it's a bug or something else.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution that works fine in Ubuntu 18.04.

Once you've opened Visual Studio Code, just press `alt + space` and the system menu will appear, then you just have to select the `Always on top` option.

Comment: This is driving me nuts for the reverse reason, as vscode starts out as 'always on top', and I'm using vscode to debug standalone executable. I cant see it run without minimizing, and in WSL (not ubuntu proper) unchecking always on top makes vscode unstable and eventually crash, or crash another vscode in another Window. Using 2.30.2 on Ubuntu (18.04) and VcXsrv all latest as of day of post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but with external application : is call DESK PIN u can DL it [HERE](https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]In Windows, you can simply do that by installing **Microsoft PowerToys**.

First, go and install Powertoys from here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install

There is a feature called "**Always On Top**" and you can activate it after installing this software by using the [ **Win + Ctrl + T** ] shortcut. You should enable this feature inside of the window you want to be on top.